# Magento2 installation is failing at 51%

Tags: magento2, installation

> Module 'Magento_Theme': [ERROR] InvalidArgumentException: Wrong file
>   in
>   C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php:64

Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(55): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->open('C:/xampp7.3.15/...') #1 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(36): Magento\Framework\Image->open() #2 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Image->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2), 'C:/xampp7.3.15/...') #3 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #4 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #5 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Factory.php(47): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #6 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\View\Design\Theme\Image.php(127): Magento\Framework\Image\Factory->create('C:/xampp7.3.15/...') #7 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(135): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Image->createPreviewImage('C:/xampp7.3.15/...')
#8 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(114): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_savePreviewImage(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
#9 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(73): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_registerThemeRecursively(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
#10 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\module-theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes.php(47): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->register() #11 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php(162): Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes->apply() #12 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1010): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme')
#13 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(879): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #14 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #15 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(368): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #16 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #17 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #18 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#19 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #20 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(116): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #21 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #22 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #23 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #24 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #25 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #26 {main} Next Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Unable to apply data patch Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes for module Magento_Theme. Original exception message: Wrong file in C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php:170 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1010): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme')
#1 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(879): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #2 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #3 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(368): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #5 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #6 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #8 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(116): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #9 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #10 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #11 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #12 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13 C:\xampp7.3.15\htdocs\DemoWebsite\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #14 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Go to Below file and replace this function*

> vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
  {
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);
      if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
          return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
```

**Again reinstall**

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by following the below link.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28055

Comment: Please add the full answer so, it may help others properly.

Answer (score 0):

Find `validateURLScheme` function in `vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php` file. at line 96. Replace function with this:

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
  {
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);
      if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
          return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
```

**Try Again ** It will work 100%.